# AEM/CQ: Why does Hobbes run in edit mode?

Tags: aem, functional-testing

When running Hobbes functional tests in Adobe Experience Manager 6, the page being tested loads with wcmmode=edit.

This seems counter intuitive, surely the functional tests should be testing the site that users will see? Is this intentional? Is it sufficient to just call .navigateTo('pathto/mypage.html?wcmmode=disabled') inside the Hobbes test, to override this?

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry to resurrect an old thread, but I thought it might be useful to answer for others who visit this question!)

I've been experimenting with writing some Hobbes functional tests on AEM 6.1 and wondered the same thing, whether the edit mode would interfere with the tests.

However, it appears that the tests do run in some sort of alternate environment from the regular 'edit' mode. When searching for CSS Elements in the javascript console from the Developer section of the edit mode, I get no returned objects. When searching from the console on a live page, the expected elements do show up, and they also return normally to the Hobbes framework when using `hobs.find('#foo')`.

```
.addTestCase(new hobs.TestCase("Some events show up within the component")
  .asserts.isTrue(function () {
    // `hobs.find('blah')` returns an array of elements matching the selector
    // here I am expecting there to be some events in the widget 
    return hobs.find('div.events-wrap a.event').length > 0;
  }));
```

Hope that helps, or that you already got the answer to your question!

-gvh